# What would be the easiest way to provide a way to configure a tree of objects to the user?

Tags: c#, winforms, user-interface

So I have an object tree that looks similar to this:

```
AbstractA
    string PropA
    int PropB
    AbstractC PropC
    AbstractD PropD

AbstractB
    string PropA
    string PropB

AbstractC : AbstractB
    string PropC

AbstractD : AbstractB
    int PropC

ConcreteA1 : AbstractA
    int PropE

ConcreteC1 : AbstractC
    bool PropD

ConcreteC2 : AbscractC
    decimal PropD

ConcreteD1 : AbstractD
    string PropD
ConcreteD2 : AbstractD
    long PropD
```

The issue I'm having is finding a comprehensive way to provide the user with the ability to configure the object tree. There are multiple concrete classes that extend my abstracts and I would like to refrain from building a user control for every concrete type. To throw an additional constraint in the mix, the class definition is coming from my WCF proxy class. I'd like to avoid rolling my own proxy/model definitions if at all possible, but if the only way to accomplish my goal is to do so then so be it.

I originally tried to use PropertyGrid but my knowledge of it is pretty weak and I wasn't having much luck googling any good examples last night.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it sounds like you are using .net on both sides of the interaction and have control of both sides.  if this is the case, instead of generating proxy classes, you could put the contracts into a common assembly referenced by both the service and the client and use the contract classes and interfaces directly instead of using generated proxies and thereby have complete control over the classes being used and have the ability to use whatever attributes you desire.

Comment: I hadn't realized that was possible for some strange reason. I guess I'm still living in the days of WebServices... I'll give that a shot.

Comment: it's my preference to do wcf that way.  easy to create a proxy instance with channelfactory http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms576132.aspx.  that way you don't have the step of regenerating all the time to keep your proxy in sync if you have contract changes.

Comment: It's been a lot of work to implement All the property descriptors and custom type descriptors, but not nearly as much as making a separate control for each concrete type. Now I just need to figure out how to get my char[] collection editor to accept \t... lol

Answer (score 0):

To avoid building a control for each type, you need to use reflection on each object's properties and convert the data to and from easy to manipulate strings.  A grid control with two columns, the left side for property names and the right for their values (as strings).  When an edit takes place, converts the value to the right type.  Every base type has an inherit converter that is relatively easy to access.

Your grid/listview needs to be a list of properties, and these properties need to map to your class instance.  The list of objects will represent each property of the item(your concrete object). The list of objects will need to remember a few things, the item, the property info of the property and the value, plus whatever else you want the grid to do based on the property information.

Using Reflection and TypeConverter's you can get at each property and edit their values and therefore create one control(the grid/listview of properties for a class instance) to edit any of your classes.

Comment: Isn't that the PropertyGrid control you are rebuilding there?

Comment: It may be, I've never used the PropertyGrid control.

Comment: I'm trying to use the ProperyGrid control already, the issue I've run across is my objects are generated from WCF Metadata. Adding attributes to the properties doesn't work.